# Etymologie des Wortes »gären«

Tags: etymology

Als ich heute das Wort *gären* gelernt habe, habe ich es sofort mit der (vergärten) römischen Sauce [Garum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garum) assoziiert. Das kann natürlich nur ein Trick sein, um sich das Wort einfach zu merken, aber ich vermute, es gibt eine etymologische Verbindung.

Leider könnte ich nichts dazu online finden. Kann jemanden mir helfen?

Comment: Hier ist die Herkunft erläutert: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gaeren

Comment: Vielen Dank für das Link Iris, ich sollte wahrscheinlich auch nach Synonime von "Etymologie" suchen.

Comment: Lateinisch _garum_ ist ein Lehnwort aus dem Griechischen. Als lautliche Entsprechung zu einem griechischen *g-* würde man im Deutschen *k-* erwarten; daher dürften _garum_ und _gären_ nicht urverwandt sein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nach dem etymolgischen Wörterbuch ([DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=g%C3%A4ren)) stammt das Verb **gären** vom althochdeutschen *jesan* (in Gärung geraten, schäumen), das wiederum seine Wurzeln im altindischen *yásyati* haben soll. Erst mit zwei Lautverschiebungen *j* > *g* und *s* > *r* wurde schon im Mittelhochdeutschen daraus *jesen, gesen, jernn* und *ger(e)n*, das im Neuhochdeutschen noch den Umlaut erhielt *e* > *ä*. Interessanterweise kommt auch das englische *yeast* (Hefe) aus dem gleichen Stamm.

Die wird so auch von den [Grimms](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG01132#XGG01132) beschrieben.

Eine etymologische Gemeinsamkeit mit der römischen Fischpaste *garum* ist nicht bekannt.

Comment: Beachte auch das schwedische Wort _jäst_, das _Hefe_ bedeutet.

Comment: Engl. yeast ist evtl. bekannter.

Comment: Vielen Dank, ich finde das Wörterbuch DWDS insbesondere wertvoll